# How can we upgrade PHP in present available wamp installed in Windows?

Tags: php, wamp

I was installing the Moodle on my machine and faced a problem of requirement of Greater version of PHP which is not available in present version in wamp.

So couuld anyone suggest me:  How can we upgrade PHP in present available wamp installed in Windows ?

Comment: Have you downloaded your WAMP setup from a specific website? If so, which one and which version? Maybe there is a new version available already?

Comment: @genesis: Can be a development machine as well, so must not.

Comment: If you mean Wampserver, then instructions and downloads are here: http://www.wampserver.com/en/addons_php.php

Comment: @genesis: It's okay to ask development related questions here on SO when it's about getting the development system to run according to ones needs.

Comment: Gentlemen, please take the further discussion to meta or chat

Comment: @hakre: ok, deleted my comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You download the addon you want from [WampServer addons](http://www.wampserver.com/addons_php.php), and execute it. It will add a context menu entry in WampManager letting you choose between the different installed PHP versions.

Comment: Does this affect already existing applications running on wamp? Is this safe?

Comment: if there is the release u want, how if it dosent?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,28732) article.

- Just backup your data
- Uninstall WAMP
- Install new WAMP

**or download [this executable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/WampServer2-PHP531.exe/download) and execute it**