# Hex2bin is not working when I am trying to use it to convert encoded data to binary

Tags: php

I was using bin2hex() function it is working when I tried to get the original value using hex2bin() then it is saying that "undefined function". any solution?

Comment: Which is your php version..?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hex2bin is available with PHP Version >= 5.4.0 - is your PHP version up 2 date?

Below (copied from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php#110973)) is a solution if your version can not be updated:

```
<?php 
        function hextobin($hexstr) 
    { 
        $n = strlen($hexstr); 
        $sbin="";   
        $i=0; 
        while($i<$n) 
        {       
            $a =substr($hexstr,$i,2);           
            $c = pack("H*",$a); 
            if ($i==0){$sbin=$c;} 
            else {$sbin.=$c;} 
            $i+=2; 
        } 
        return $sbin; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: you could update your wamp installation, I don't know it personally, but the website states a suitable PHP version in their latest download: Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.3

Comment: I have done lots of setting changes and created databases, if I install new version then maybe everything will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

- **Return Value:**    Returns the ASCII character of the converted string, or FALSE on failure
- **PHP Version:** 5+
- **Changelog:**   As of PHP 5.4.1, a warning is thrown if the input string
  is of odd length.  In PHP 5.4.0, the string was silently accepted,
  but the last byte was removed.

You can check this HEXA conversation in **PHP version 5.4.0** and above.

you just go through this [Binary function in PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and [Hexa function in PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php)

and also refer this [conversion link](http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php)

Comment: HI @CDnDT...you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292552/how-to-upgrade-php-version-in-wamp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732239/how-can-we-upgrade-php-in-present-available-wamp-installed-in-windows