# How to do hex2bin in php5.3

Tags: php, hex

`hex2bin()` function is supported after php5.4. It is not available in php5.3.  How can I do hex2bin in php3 ?

```
 echo hex2bin("48656c6c6f20576f726c6421");
```

Comment: The function `hex2bin` does not exist in PHP5.
You can use `'pack'` instead :

`$binary_string = pack("H*" , $hex_string);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php#105601

Comment: user2818066  check the answers below and mark+up-vote one answer which is correct for you.You can up-vote others also if they are useful too

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 5.3 you can use `pack`

[docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

> Pack given arguments into a binary string according to format.

```
string pack ( string $format [, mixed $args [, mixed $... ]] )
```

So you're looking for:

```
$result = pack('H*', '48656c6c6f20576f726c6421');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
 $foo = pack("H*" ,"48656c6c6f20576f726c6421");
 echo $foo
```

Answer (score 1):

hex2bin is available with PHP Version >= 5.4.0 - is your PHP version up 2 date?

Below (copied from php.net) is a solution if your version can not be updated:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17963343/6775488

```
<?php 
        function hextobin($hexstr) 
    { 
        $n = strlen($hexstr); 
        $sbin="";   
        $i=0; 
        while($i<$n) 
        {       
            $a =substr($hexstr,$i,2);           
            $c = pack("H*",$a); 
            if ($i==0){$sbin=$c;} 
            else {$sbin.=$c;} 
            $i+=2; 
        } 
        return $sbin; 
    } 
?>
```